# Why the program is showing always the same string? [+MIPS]

Tags: string, view, insert, mips, mergesort

I need to save a data that contains: name, id and rating.
So the insert command is kind this one:

```
addi $sp, $sp, -12
li $v0,8           # take in input
la $a0, buffer     # load byte space into address
move $t0,$a0       # save string to t0
syscall

sw $t0, 0($sp)     # name
sw $t1, 4($sp)     # id
sw $t2, 8($sp)     # rating
addi $t7,$t7,1     # number of elements
```

The view command is kind this one:

```
loop:
    beq $t6, $t7, end

    lw $a0, 0($sp)    # name
    li $v0, 4
    syscall

    lw $a0, 4($sp)    # id
    li $v0, 1
    syscall

    lw $a0, 8($sp)    # rating
    li $v0, 1
    syscall

addi $t6,$t6, 1
addi $sp,$sp, 12
j loop
```

When make two elements the first one: `aa, 12, 12 second one : bb, 13, 13`
After the view command is this: `aa, 12, 12 second one: aa, 13, 13`

Can you help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're passing the same address (`buffer`) to the `read_string` syscall every time. So each call will overwrite the string from the previous call.

You need to have separate buffers for every string. You could for example pass `buffer` to syscall 8, then calculate the length of the read string, allocate memory for it (including the NULL-terminator) [using syscall 9](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/lab/secondyear/spim/node8.html), copy the string from `buffer` to your newly allocated block of memory, and finally store the address of the allocated memory on the stack instead of `buffer`'s.